# How do I change the colour of markers (arrow heads)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want my markers the same colour as the lines/links they represent when I click a button.

I make the arrows here :

```
  var arrows = inner.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", "arrow") // changed to - .attr("id", function(d){ return 'arrow' + d.name})
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 20) 
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr("markerWidth", 10) //size of arrow head
            .attr("markerHeight", 10)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .style("stroke-width", lineWidth)
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
            .style("stroke", "steelblue");
```

I add the arrows to the links :

```
var links = svg.selectAll(".link").append("g")
.style("marker-end", "url(#arrow)") //-changed to - .style("marker-end", function(d,i){ return 'url(#arrow' + d.name+ ')' })
```

Now I have made a button to change the colour of the links :

```
var links = inner.selectAll("line.link")
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

And tried to do it with the marker, but this doesnt seem to work

```
var arrows = inner.selectAll("#arrow")
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

I am using the same data in the markers as I am in the links which I thought was the original problem but Ive hit a wall and don't know how to do it.

Here is an example that works which I have tried working from but still cant seem to get mine working

"http://bl.ocks.org/dustinlarimer/5888271"

Comment: could you give us a demo to better help you?

Comment: Im sorry I cant give the whole document just yet, is there anything particular you are looking for me to add ? @GraceLee

Comment: just was looking for like a little demo (not the whole document, just like a snippet that replicates the problem) to fiddle with. its hard to figure out the problem with css without looking at the object, especially since i (and some of the rest of us) havent worked with d3.js, but if the solution lies outside of the dependency of d3.js, we could possibly help

Comment: ah okay, I understand, Ill try get an example together quickly :) But i do think the problem is with D3 :/

Comment: You seem to be setting the `style` (instead of an `attr`) `marker-end` style on `g`s instead of on `line`, `path`, `polyline` or `polygon` elements. I am surprised that it works at all.

Comment: For what its worth, you _can_ do what you were originally trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/r3q5z60s/ However, it will change the color of the marker at all the places where it is used. Changes: select the `path` inside the `marker`, not just the `marker`.

Comment: yeah I figured that out, I want them the same colour as the line they represent though as said in the question. Thanks though :)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/r3q5z60s this demo works good for changing arrow color. But how to change the color for a solid arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the color of the same marker individually to correspond to the color of the line on-the-fly. The only way to do it is to create separate markers that are each colored differently in your defs with ids or classes that correspond to the colors you want and then use those CSS selectors.

You'll notice in the example you link to, the markers are defined with their color and shape and are individually referenced by the corresponding line.

Comment: literally just figured that out after reading - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/08uROmH28HA. Thanks for the help

Comment: Frustrated the heck out of me until I understood it. Doesn't really make sense to me, but that's how SVG markers were defined.

Comment: haha atleast I'm not the only one. Another question, don't know if you'll see this or know the answer, as said in the question I click a button then the links+markers are suppose to change colour. How do I do a selectAll(Markers) so I can colour them differently. Ill update the original question to show what I have updated. @elijah

Comment: You don't. You define a separate marker for each color you want, then you update the url() ref in your "marker-end" attr whenever you want to change the color.

Comment: how to I do this with a colorScale where I dont know how many different coloured markers I will need ? Bit slow today, bare with me

Comment: You don't, unless you plan to make a hundred/thousand/million different markers. You should use d3.scale.quantize to create discrete color categories and create markers associated with them. If you really need a linear color ramp, you could create markers with each new color, but that's bad design and will cause performance issues. Here's d3.scale.quantize with colors in case you're not familiar: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/ea5760799fce0b3a2e7c

Comment: sorted. big thanks for that, once I figured out I was drawing the markers with one id I was able to give them seperate ID's and then colour them individually :) appreciate the help